# Django - How to link the current authenticated user with the data provided by a form

Tags: django, django-forms

Sorry if the question is too basic but I've read the documentation and many articles and none of them seem to answer my question.

I want to link a posted form by an user with that user into the DB, so I can query the data provided for each particular user and use delete on CASCADE in the event the user is deleted.

I tried creating a Model, then a ModelForm based on that Model.
I added a field named "user" in the Model as a ForeignKey, so in the ModelForm is translated to ModelChoiceField which by the way is hidden, since the user shouldn't change that value.
But when I try to update the user field in the views.py, nothing happens, the form is saved into the DB, but the user field remains as None or Null in the DB.

models.py

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='+', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

forms.py

```py
class FooForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Foo
        fields = ['user', 'field1', 'field2']
        exclude = ['user']
```

views.py

```py
def index(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        if request.method == 'POST':
        foo = FooForm(request.POST)
        if foo.is_valid():
            foo.save(commit=False)
            foo.user = request.user 
            foo.save()
```

I got the posted Form saved into the DB but the user field is NULL.
Please tell me if you see any errors in my code or if there is a better way to achieve what I want. 
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are quite close. But `foo` is the *form*, not the instance. You can alter the instance by writing `foo.instance.user = request.user`. For example:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

@login_required
def index(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        if request.method == 'POST':
        foo = FooForm(request.POST)
        if foo.is_valid():
            foo.instance.user = request.user
            foo.save()
    # …
```

You probably want to decorate your view with the [**`@login_required`** decorator [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.decorators.login_required), such that in case there is no authenticated user, it will redirect to the login page.

Comment: Thank you very much !
You just solve my issue, and also thanks for the additional advice.